# Hide Wordpress Plugin Jsquery object with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, css

I've been over a week trying every option to hide an object which is the results of a wordpress plugin. I would like to hide it using CSS as my WP is managed and I have limited access to code.

The website is https://www.heatingbargains.co.uk

and the object is the right hand bottom corner Google reviews badge which says "no rating available"

[image: screenshot]

I need a CSS code that I can use to call the classes and make the badge dissapear, when doing live editing I can get it to dissapear but when I call one of the many classes on the div I cannot get it to work through the "additional CSS" edit in WP.

These are the classes I've tried calling:

```
.tWrghb
.rCjEAf
.YW8Nub
```

Comment: looks like it's a shadow dom webcomponent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
div#___ratingbadge_0 {
  left: -99999px;
}
```

It's hard to set any styles on this because so much is set inline but I think this might knock the rating badge div off the screen so the user wont see it.